# Sciposter setting A0 page dimensions

Tags: paper-size, sciposter

I’m doing my first A0 poster with LaTeX; after some experiences with web examples I´m using a sciposter template (with multicols and sections) which I find very simple; but when I run it I get a PDF file with all the information there but with 1 third of the page all white;
first I assume that geometry package, for setting the page dimensions, would solve the problem, but it seems that nothing works; just need a full page poster… but actually when using `\usepackage{fullpage}` nothing happens; can somebody please help me out?

```
\documentclass{sciposter}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuges]{babel}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref,amsfonts,multicol}
\usepackage[paperwidth=84cm,paperheight=120cm,centering,textwidth=74cm,textheight=100cm,left=2cm,top=2cm]{geometry}
\hypersetup{pdfpagelayout=SinglePage}
\usepackage{graphicx,colortbl}
\pagestyle{plain}
%\usepackage{fullpage}
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't need **geometry**, as **sciposter** has support for A0 paper:

```
\documentclass[a0]{sciposter}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuges]{babel}

\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts,multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx,colortbl}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfpagelayout=SinglePage}

\pagestyle{plain}
```

Note that T1 encoding is recommended for languages with many accented letters and that **hyperref** should generally be loaded last.